# htaccess rewrite,remove string

Tags: php, .htaccess, colors, hex

I want to make a php website for checking the colorhex code,
now I have one problem while checking the code,
my script is

```
<?php
echo'
<html><head><style>
body{
background-color:#'.$_GET['c'].';
}
</style></head><body></body></html>';
?>
```

and I type the url `http://example.com/?c=FF0000`
will display the background-color as red, but I want to hide the ?c= with modding the htaccess  file,I have googled and tried but no one works,anyone know how to do this?

Comment: How about using `POST` instead of `GET`?

Comment: The question does not make sense in its current state. You have to edit it and add more information for us to understand: certainly it is possibe to use rewriting here, but somehow you must hand over the color you want to display. So if not as query arguments, how else do you want to do that? Like that maybe: `http://site.com/FF0000` or by posting the value?

Comment: I want to make a site like:http://www.colorhexa.com/33b5e5

Comment: Look at [mod-rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mod-rewrite/info) for some howtos. It's *trivial* in your case.

Comment: yea,I want to make the url like http://site.com/FF0000,also have a input box for enter the hex code in homepage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this in the server configuration or a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]{6})$ index.php?c=$1 [L]
```

If you run into problems with rewriting it always is a very good idea to use the loggin facility apaches rewriting module brings along. Read the manual about the two configuration options `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel`, they give you a wealth of additional information that helps to understand what is actually going on during the rewrite.

Comment: this not working,when I type /?c=FF0000 it can display the color,but I type /FF0000 it display 404 page.

Comment: Well, how is the script called that you cite in your question? I assumed it is called index.php...

Comment: I added a hint to use the logging facility. This helps you to find out what is actually called internally.

Comment: You are welcome. Now you just have to accept the answer by ticking the checkmark below the voting arrows.

Comment: hello,one more question.
I want to make a input box for manually enter hex code
I tried `if(isset($_GET['c'])){ $hex = $_GET['c']; } if(!isset($GET['c'])){ $hex = $_POST['search']; }` but not working.

Comment: Please open a new question, since this is a separate thing. In the question you must cite your html markup and the processing php code. Otherwise people can only guess what you are doing...